# How I can completly reinstall VirtualBox 5.1?

Tags: apt, 18.04, virtualbox

When I want to start VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 18.04, I get a message like this:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

I tried to reinstall Virtualbox by following, but after that, the same message was there still:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Now my question is: Are there things I have to do (or I can do) in addition to the `apt` command?

Thank you very much for an answer in advance

Edit: `dpkg -S /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so` prints
`virtualbox: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so`

Comment: purge dont delete the product, it only removed configuration files. `sudo apt uninstall --purge virtualbox` should delete totally. You could try `sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox` instead of uninstalling and installing, though.

Comment: The problem of your idea is, that `apt` has not a command called `uninstall`.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so` to the question. It is very likely that package is named `virtualbox-5.1` - so you should use `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1` and `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1`.

Comment: I added the information above.

Comment: Did you try to `sudo apt purge virtualbox*` and then download .deb package file from [Virtualbox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) installing it with `dpkg -i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may delete your virtualbox with

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox
```

and you may reinstall it from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Adam and Pablo Bianchi!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled virtualisation in the bios.

Comment: It was enabled.